# Testing conditions using Character pointers

Tags: c++, c

```
int main()
{
  char *p,c;
  for(p="Hello World";c=*p;++p)
  {
    printf("%c",c);
  }
}
```

In the above code,i know that ++p will make pointer 'p' point to next character in the "Hello World".And i also know that there is no boundary checking performed on arrays in C or C++.The output of the program is 'Hello World'. How am i able to test conditions using

```
c=*p;
```

What does 'c=*p' return.As far as my understanding goes, when '++p' reaches the end of the 'hello world', pointer 'p' should point to some garbage value and the loop should print some garbage values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C strings are by definition terminated by a NULL character `'\0'`, if it is a string then it has to end it in a NULL. therefore `c = *p` will point to a NULL character when the string ends, which is in your case the immediately next character of `'d'`. And the NULL character in the ASCII table has an integer value 0, which evaluates to false and gets out of the `for` loop.

Note that if a C string does not end in a NULL character (then at first it is not a C string), then basically there is no way of detecting that it is a string, as it will be stores as a sequence of bytes. In that case it will be simply a byte array or a string, will depend on how we interpret.

Also not that `c = *p` does not *return* anything, it is an expression and it is *evaluated*. `e = *p` transfers the value pointed by the current value of `p` into the var `c`, the value of which is the final evaluation of the expression.

Comment: Got it.Very helpful.Can u briefly explain the difference in using '=' vs '==' for testing conditions.

Comment: @tez If you use `c=x`, `c` will be evaluated after `x` is assigned to it. `c==x` evaluates whether `c` and `x` are equal.

Comment: @tez: see what Luchian Grigore says. `=` is an assignment operator, it will transfer the value of the variable on the right hand side it the variable in the left hand side. On the other hand `==` is a comparison operator. if the right hand side expression `a` and the left hand side expression `b` of `==` are equal then the expression `a == b` will evaluate to true, if they are not same then the expression will evaluate as false. I would recommend having a look at any good C book first to get into these basic stuffs in C.

Comment: @phoxis,@Luchian Grigore Perfect.Thnx a ton :)

Answer (score 9):

`c=*p;` doesn't return anything, it's an expression. The `for` loop **evaluates** the value of `c` after the assignment.

> when '++p' reaches the end of the 'hello world', pointer 'p' should point to some garbage value

Not really. Before reaching the end, it reaches the **null terminating character** - `'\0'`. Which is `0`. Which is assigned to `c` and evaluates the break condition to `false`. So the loop finishes **before** it goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Strings are terminated by a null character (aka with `\0`), so then at the end `p` should point to the null character that terminates the string, thus `c` would be `\0` which is considered a false condition.